# Pairing two Pandas data frames with an ID value

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-analysis

I am trying to put together a useable set of data about glaciers. Our original data comes from an ArcGIS dataset, and latitude/longitude values were stored in a separate file, now detached from the CSV with all of our data. I am attempting to merge the latitude/longitude files with our data set. Heres a preview of what the files look like.

This is my main dataset file, **glims** (columns dropped for clarity)

```
| ANLYS_ID | GLAC_ID        | AREA  |
|----------|----------------|-------|
| 101215   | G286929E46788S | 2.401 |
| 101146   | G286929E46788S | 1.318 |
| 101162   | G286929E46788S | 0.061 |
```

This is the latitude-longitude file, **coordinates**

```
| lat   |   long  |        glacier_id |
|-------|---------|----------------|
| 1.187 | -70.166 | G001187E70166S |
| 2.050 | -70.629 | G002050E70629S |
| 3.299 | -54.407 | G002939E70509S |
```

The problem is, the **coordinates** data frame has one row for each glacier id with latitude longitude, whereas my **glims** data frame has multiple rows for each glacier id with varying data for each entry.

I need every single entry in my main data file to have a latitude-longitude value added to it, based on the matching glacier_id between the two data frames.

Heres what I've tried so far.

```
glims = pd.read_csv('glims_clean.csv')
coordinates = pd.read_csv('LatLong_GLIMS.csv')

df['que'] = np.where((coordinates['glacier_id'] == 
glims['GLAC_ID']))
```

error returns: 'int' object is not subscriptable

and:

```
glims.merge(coordinates, how='right', on=('glacier_id', 'GLAC_ID'))
```

error returns: int' object has no attribute 'merge'

I have no idea how to tackle this big of a merge. I am also afraid of making mistakes because it is nearly impossible to catch them, since the data carries no other identifying factors.

Any guidance would be awesome, thank you.

Comment: can you show us glims.info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
glims = glims.merge(coordinates, how='left', left_on='GLAC_ID', right_on='glacier_id')
```

Answer (score 1):

This a classic merging problem. One way to solve is using straight `loc` and index-matching

```
glims = glims.set_index('GLAC_ID')

glims.loc[:, 'lat']  = coord.set_index('glacier_id').lat
glims.loc[:, 'long'] = coord.set_index('glacier_id').long

glims = glims.reset_index()
```

---

You can also use `pd.merge`

```
pd.merge(glims,
         coord.rename(columns={'glacier_id': 'GLAC_ID'}), 
         on='GLAC_ID')
```